# Normalized States

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

A linear functional is normalized iff it preserves identity: $$\|\omega\|=1 \iff \omega(\mathrm{id})=1$$
Can somebody help me proving it?
*(I just remember it was kind of an easy thing.)*

Comment: See theorem 3.3.3 in C-star-algebras and operator theory. G. Murphy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is stated, the property is not true. For example, consider the linear functional on $M_2(\mathbb C)$, 
$$
\omega:\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\mapsto a-d.
$$
Then $\omega(\text{id})=0$, so a normalized version of $\omega$ will fail the assertion.

The result is true, however, when $\omega$ is required to be *positive*.

For 
any $x$, we have $x^*x\leq\|x^*x\|\,\text{id}$. Using Kadison's Schwarz inequality ($\omega(x)^*\omega(x)\leq\omega(x^*x)$),
$$
|\omega(x)|^2\leq\omega(x^*x)\leq\|x^*x\|\,\omega(\text{id})=\|x\|^2\,\omega(\text{id}).
$$
This implies that $\|\omega\|\leq\omega(\text{id})\leq\|\omega\|$. So $\|\omega\|=\omega(\text{id})$.

A less trivial result is the fact that if a linear functional satisfies $\|\omega\|=\omega(\text{id})$, then $\omega$ is positive.